# How to put in more than one row into sql with this form?

Tags: php, html, sql

Hi could someone help me insert more than row into my sql database with this form? I have tried searching online but a lot of the solutions are with information which is hard coded.

This may be a bit more difficult because I am also posting a hidden variable but here goes...

Code:

(input form):

```
<?php

$essID = $_GET['essID'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ExamSubjectStudent WHERE essID = '$essID'";                       
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $esID = $row ['esID'];
        $sID = $row ['sID'];
    }

?>  

<form action="marktodatabase.php" method="post">

Mark:<input type="text" name="mark"><br />
Date:<input type="date" name="date"><br />
ExamSubject ID:<?php echo $esID;?> <input type="hidden" name="esID" value="<?php echo $esID; ?>" ><br />
Student ID:<?php echo $sID;?> <input type="hidden" name="sID" value="<?php echo $sID; ?>" ><br />

<input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

(SQL Input)

```
<?php
    $mark=$_POST['mark'];
    $date=$_POST['date'];
    $esID=$_POST['esID'];
    $sID=$_POST['sID'];

    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Results (mark, date, esID, sID) VALUES ('$mark', '$date', '$esID', '$sID')");
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

 ?>
```

This currently all works. But i'd like to put in more than one mark/date for a student..., currently I select an individual one but I'm unsure how to make it so more than one mark/date/esID/sID/ is shown.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to edit your form so the output of the inputs is inside your PHP Loop.
Then all the inputs will need the esID and sID in their names, so you can identify them later. No need for the hidden inputs anymore.

```
<form action="marktodatabase.php" method="post">
<?php
    $essID = $_GET['essID'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ExamSubjectStudent WHERE essID = '$essID'";                       
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
        $esID = $row['esID'];
        $sID = $row['sID'];

        echo "Mark: <input type=\"text\" name=\"mark_".$esID."_".$sID."\"><br />";
        echo "Date: <input type=\"date\" name=\"date_".$esID."_".$sID."\"><br />";
        echo "ExamSubject ID:".$esID."<br />";
        echo "Student ID: ".$sID."<br />";
    }
?>  

<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Then for saving, you need to loop over all the rows you previously selected, check if they have been changed and then save them.

```
<?php
$essID = $_GET['essID'];
$sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM ExamSubjectStudent WHERE essID = '$essID'";                       
$result = mysql_query($sqlSelect);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $new_mark=$_POST['mark_'.$row['esId'].'_'.$row['sID']];
    $new_date=$_POST['date_'.$row['esId'].'_'.$row['sID']];
    $old_mark=$row['mark'];
    $old_date=$row['date'];

    if($new_mark != $old_mark || $new_date != $old_date) {
        $sqlInsert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Results (mark, date, esID, sID) VALUES ('".$new_mark."', '".$new_date."', '".$esID."', '".$sID."')");
        $result = mysql_query($sqlInsert);
    }
}
?>
```

I didn't test this code so it might contain errors, but I hope you get the basic idea of it and can alter it to fit your needs.

EDIT: Also check the answer of Dipendu Paul on how to insert multiple rows in one query. You might use that in combination with my script.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of multiple inserts in a single query would be like below:

```
INSERT INTO Results (mark, date, esID, sID) VALUES ('$mark1', '$date1', '$esID1', '$sID1')
                                                  ,('$mark2', '$date2', '$esID2', '$sID2') 
                                                  , ....more paranthesized comma separated values here;
```

You can construct the query in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert multiple values in mysql.Add comma (,) among every set of values in insert statement.

Below is the example.
"INSERT INTO user(name,lastname) "
            . "VALUES('test','testing'),('testing','testing1'),('testing1','testing2') "

You can check mysql tutorial also for this.